# Get values of type number from sqlite - getting text istead

Tags: php, text, pdo, sqlite, numbers

I don't know if it is a PHP issue, or PDO issue, or SQLITE issue, but when I search for values in columns which have NUMBER data type, or simply retrieve a SUM of them, php get them as string istead of number (integer, float...)

```
<?php
//...
$res = $pdo->query("SELECT SUM(id) as 'foo' FROM anytable");
$bar = $res->fetch(); //this value should be (int)
$bar['test'] = 12.50; //this value is (float)
$bar['test'] = 666; //this value is (int)
echo json_encode($bar);
?>
```

I get this object:

```
{ foo: "580", test: 12.50, test2: 666 }
```

This is a sample code, my real query is really more complex and I don't want to parse every field (roughly 90) as integer or float, since they are mixed data type

---

**EDIT:** As noted by [VolKerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk), the implementation in PDO for sqlite is fairly poor. I tested the feature proposed `$pdostmt->getColumnMeta( $intColId )` which give us some hint. Since they don't match syntactically the sqlite driver types, I'll test something more and leave here result by time, if anyone is interested.

```
$hints = $pdostmt->getColumnMeta( $intColId );
$coltype = $hints['native_type'];
```

results:

```
sqlite data type  |  native_type
---------------------------------
DECIMAL           |  'double'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there are sqlite functions like sqlite3_column_double() or sqlite3_column_int() which would allow to return a range of "native" types, [the function behind PDOStatement::fetch() when using the sqlite driver](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_statement.c#L264) is currently limited to `NULL`, `sqlite3_column_blob()` and as the default for any other type: `sqlite3_column_text()`. So, regardless of whether the storage type is INTEGER,REAL or TEXT, you will get ...text.

But at least [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) can tell you a bit more about the native type. The [sqlite driver distinguishes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_statement.c#L293) between SQLITE_NULL, SQLITE_FLOAT, SQLITE_BLOB, SQLITE_TEXT and SQLITE_INTEGER.

Comment: than you very much. didn't expect to have this issue to deal with... at least sqlite sql code does math. hoping the *experimental* getColumnMeta doesn't change much and stabilize. bye!